# How would you update a Flow in the repository from a server call without saving it locally?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

How would you update a Flow in the repository from a server call without saving it locally?

I have two functions "launch" in the ViewModel: one makes a request to the server that returns an AppError, and the other listens to the Flow to which I assign the data received from the server. All of this without saving data locally; I don't need to.

Fragment

```
private fun collectState() {
     with(viewModel.state) {
        diff(viewLifecycleOwner, {it.centers}) { centers ->
            log("Centros: $centers")
     }
}

fun <T, U> Flow<T>.diff(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, mapf: (T) -> U, body: (U) -> Unit) {
    lifecycleOwner.launchAndCollect(
        flow = map(mapf).distinctUntilChanged(),
        body = body
    )
}

fun <T> LifecycleOwner.launchAndCollect(
    flow: Flow<T>,
    state: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED,
    body: (T) -> Unit
) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        this@launchAndCollect.repeatOnLifecycle(state) {
            flow.collect(body)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
init {
   launchGetCenters()
}

fun onUiReady {
    launchRequestCentersUseCase()
}

private fun launchGetCenters() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        getCentersUseCase()
            .catch { cause -> _state.update { it.copy(appError = cause.toError()) } }
            .collect { centers ->
                _state.update { it.copy(centers = centers) }
            }
    }
}

private fun launchRequestCentersUseCase() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _state.value = _state.value.copy(progress = true)
        val error = requestCentersUseCase()
        _state.update { _state.value.copy(progress = false, appError = error) }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
private var _centers: MutableStateFlow<List<Center>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
val centers = _centers.asStateFlow()

suspend fun requestCenters(): AppError? {
    val response: Either<AppError, List<Center?>> = remoteDataSource.requestCenters()
    response.fold(ifLeft = { return it }) { centers ->
          //_centers.emit(centers.filterNotNull())
          //_centers.update { centers.filterNotNull() }
          _centers.value = centers.filterNotNull()
    }
    return null
}
```

The use cases are calls to the repository:

```
class GetCentersUseCase @Inject constructor(private val repository: RemoteRepository) {
    operator fun invoke(): Flow<List<Center>> = repository.centers
}
```

```
class RequestCentersUseCase @Inject constructor(private val repository: RemoteRepository) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(): AppError? = repository.requestCenters()
}
```

The List is downloaded, but the launchGetCenters() function, which is listening to the Flow in the ViewModel, is not notified of the change; it only receives an initial empty list.

What could be happening?

Comment: What type does `remoteDataSource.requestCenters()` return? The functions `launchGetCenters()` and `launchRequestCenters()` are quite unusual. Basically you have to remember to call these functions to make your other Flow work at all and there’s a risk of accidentally calling them multiple times and wasting resources (very easy to do with functions called from `Activity.onCreate()` or `Fragment.onViewCreated()`—usually you would expect a flow to just work when you start collecting it. I can’t see any good reason to have it the way you do.

Comment: Would have to see how you are calling these functions and how you’re observing the relevant flows to tell you what’s going wrong.

Comment: The `requestCenters()` function throws away any non-error result. Not sure if this is your intent.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I suspect `remoteDataSource.requestCenters()` returns an `Either` from Arrow.kt. Left side is an error, right side is a success. `requestCenters()` doesn't throw away non-error results, but assign them to the flow. But yes, this is unusual that errors are handled entirely different than success.

Comment: How do you observe `ifRight` was invoked and how do you observe `collect {}` in `launchGetCenters()` was not?

Comment: If Either.fold synchronously unwraps and returns either the left or right, then to me it looks like that function unwraps the right side to pass to the flow and just allows the left side to be released to the GC. It always returns null, which is weird.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Please note `return it` doesn't return from the lambda, but from the `requestCenters()`.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

I've added the return of requestCenters(). AS @broot said it is a Either.

I treat the action of calling the server and the action of getting the data separately because for example I could in the requestCenters() function save the data in local and retrieve it in the getCenters() function from local. In fact, if I do it like this, the flow works.

Comment: @TenFour04 remoteDataSource.requestCenters() return an AppError or a null. If the AppError is null means that it isn't an error (it was ok).

Comment: Understood. I think we're getting sidetracked by all the discussion of internals of `requestCenters()`. Please see my first two comments about the information we need to be able to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your support.

launchGetCenters() and launchRequestCenters() are executed in the init() and onUiReady() from ViewModel and are observed from the fragment.
I have added this code.

If I saved requestCenters() response in local and retrieve it in the getCenters() function from local, the flow works.

@Tenfour04  what else do you need to know?

Comment: So you're saying that if `requestCenters()` updates a local database instead of the `_centers` flow, and instead you have the `_centers` flow simply read from the database, then everything works? What does the definition of `LifecycleOwner.launchAndCollect()` look like? So far I can't detect the exact issue, but your Flow setup does seem convoluted.

Comment: Yeah, this works:



`val centers: Flow<List<Centers>> = localDataSource.getCenters()`



`
suspend fun requestCenters(): AppError? {
    val response: Either<AppError, List<Center?>> = remoteDataSource.requestCenters()
    response.fold(ifLeft = { return it }) { centers ->
           localDataSource.save(centers)
    }
    return null
}`

Comment: @Tenfour04 I've added LifecycleOwner.launchAndCollect() to the fragment, see above (althougt it is a extension function)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot spot the source of the problem. I could suggest a significant simplification to your design, which may or may not result in eliminating the problem.